# Align Left under Centered Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a solution to align a sublist directly under a centered main-point. Here are some images to let you know what I want to achieve:

[image]

But for now, when I have a centered main list point (LEISTUNGEN), I can't get the sublist where I want it to be. I can center it:

[image]

The main problem is, that the main-list-point is variable in width, so I can't just use a padding for the sub-list to put it under LEISTUNGEN.

Anyone knows a possible solution?

Here's my structure:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li><a href="#">Leistungen</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">mehr Leistungen</a>
      <li><a href="#">Leistungen 2</a>
      <li><a href="#">Und noch mehr davon</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS so far:

```
.mainmenu {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    padding-top:12px;
}
.mainmenu > li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
.mainmenu > li > a {
    display:block;
    color: #636466;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.mainmenu ul {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.mainmenu ul > li {
    position:relative;
}
.mainmenu ul > li > a {
    color:#1a4787;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your css with the below, also include `list-style:none` to the class `.mainmenu ul > li`

**CSS**

```
.mainmenu ul{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tpdj2gzg/)